# Leading zero in Matlab's scientific notation

Tags: matlab, file-io, scientific-notation

In Matlab, when printing using `e` such as `fprintf('%10.5e\n', pi/100)` one will get the result to be `3.14159e-02`. However, what if I want the number to have a leading zero such as `0.314159e-1`? How can I manage this with Matlab?

The reason I ask is that I am trying to print to a file which I need to have leading zeros. Otherwise, I would not care.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any clever way to do it:

```
your_number = pi;
['0.' strrep(sprintf('%10.5e',your_number*10), '.', '')]

>> ans =

0.314159e+01
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is pretty crude but this is just to illustrate. You can do it yourself with a small function that will look for the relevant strings in the number, trim it after `e`, add `0.` in the beginning and increse by `1` the exponent at the end, for example:

```
function b=fooo(a)
b=a;
k1 = strfind(a, '.');
k2 = strfind(a, 'e-');
suffix=num2str(str2num(b(k2+1:k2+3))+1);
b(k2+1:end)=[];
b(k1)=[];
b=['0.' b suffix];
```

where an input like

```
ans=fooo(sprintf('%10.5e\n', pi/100))
```

will yield the answer:

```
ans =
   0.314159e-1
```